# Parse JSON with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to parse the following JSON with jQuery and get each id value. Can anyone advise?

```
[
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Boat"
},
{
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Cable"
}
```

]

So far I have:

```
$.each(test, function(i,item){
   alert(item);
   });
```

But that simply lists every value. How can I

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That'll list every object in your array, to get the `id` property of the one you're on, just add `.id` like this:

```
$.each(test, function(i,item){
  alert(item.id);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Nick, yes you are correct. Otherwise I would have to test for if(innerKey == 'id'). Best regards, Ben.

Answer (score 1):

If `test` is a string containing JSON, you can parse it with [`jQuery.parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/), which will return a JavaScript object.

If `test` is written like this:

```
var test = [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Boat"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Cable"
    }
];
```

...it already *is* a JavaScript object; specifically an array. [`jQuery.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) will loop through each array entry. If you want to loop through the properties of those entries as well, you can use a second loop:

```
$.each(test, function(outerKey, outerValue) {
    // At this level, outerKey is the key (index, mostly) in the
    // outer array, so 0 or 1 in your case. outerValue is the
    // object assigned to that array entry.
    $.each(outerValue, function(innerKey, innerValue) {
        // At this level, innerKey is the property name in the object,
        // and innerValue is the property's value
    });
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/evewa3)

Comment: Superb! Thank you. I was missing the jQuery.parseJSON and hence trying to itterate through a string! Best regards, Ben.