# How can I parse JSON?

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parse JSON with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4569230/parse-json-with-jquery)

I tried to parse the following JSON  File. I need to get the thumb ID from the JSON File, but I don't know how to. How can I parse the following JSON using jQuery or JavaScript?

```
[

{
    "Page": {
        "number": "0",
        "thumb": "http:\/\/cdn.data.com\/files\/aT00NTA0NCZwPTAmdmVyc2lvbj0xJmNtZD12JnNpZz0wNmRiZDQxM2I5MTdhYzZjNzJkYThhYWMyNGZlMmY0Zg%253D%253D\/-w-320.jpg"
    }
}, {
    "Page": {
        "number": "1",
        "thumb": "http:\/\/cdn.data.com\/files\/aT00NTA0NCZwPTEmdmVyc2lvbj0xJmNtZD12JnNpZz05YWI4ODVmNzZhYmQ0NWYxZmRhMmYwZmJkN2U4OTllMA%253D%253D\/-w-320.jpg"
    }
}, {
    "Page": {
        "number": "2",
        "thumb": "http:\/\/cdn.data.com\/files\/aT00NTA0NCZwPTImdmVyc2lvbj0xJmNtZD12JnNpZz1iNjA5NjJjYjIyZDQ3MjY2NWFlZDZkYzczMTdkNmMzNA%253D%253D\/-w-320.jpg"
    }
}, {
    "Page": {
        "number": "3",
        "thumb": "http:\/\/cdn.data.com\/files\/aT00NTA0NCZwPTMmdmVyc2lvbj0xJmNtZD12JnNpZz01MjY0OGMwN2MwZWJhZDYyODFjZjJhNDgxNGQ2MTIxYg%253D%253D\/-w-320.jpg"
    }
}, {
    "Page": {
        "number": "4",
        "thumb": "http:\/\/cdn.data.com\/files\/aT00NTA0NCZwPTQmdmVyc2lvbj0xJmNtZD12JnNpZz03YTAzNWE5OGVmMDFmYTgxY2Q2OTVlZTc2OGFjNTM1Mw%253D%253D\/-w-320.jpg"
    }
}

]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
var jsonObj = $.parseJSON(theJsonString);
console.log(jsonObj[0].Page.thumb);
```

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery:

```
    $.getJSON('ajax/test.json', function(data) {
     $.each(data, function(key, val) {
      //insert your code here
     });
    });
```